pROC plot shape with only one point
I've done this plot whit pROC
rocobj <- plot.roc(db$IOT, Pred,
                   main = "Confidence intervals", 
                   percent=TRUE,
                   ci = TRUE,                  
                   print.auc = TRUE)          
ciobj <- ci.se(rocobj,                         
               specificities = seq(0, 100, 5)) # over a select set of specificities
plot(ciobj, type = "shape", col = "#1c61b6AA")     
plot(ci(rocobj, of = "thresholds", thresholds = "best"))

I obtain this plot with only one point and not a stepped curve with multiple points, I think it depends on the fact that the independent variable is dichotomous, is it correct?


It makes no sense to plot an AUC curve with a dichotomous variable. If the predictor is dichotomous, just present its sensitivity, specificity and/or other relevant metrics.

Thank you @ZéLoff So I can't use either AUC or ROC. How I can compare the metrics between different predictors?

Thank you @calimo I've read the post "ROC curves with few thresholds significantly underestimate the true area under the curve (1). A ROC curve with a single point is a worst-case scenario, and any comparison with a continuous classifier will be inaccurate and misleading." but if I would like to compare AUCs all with dichotomous classifiers? Is this possible?
